# Restore RAID Drive on New OS

Tags: raid, mdadm

I had a problem with my Debian operating system on my SSD and have removed it (Debian) to install Ubuntu server. Originally, on my Debian operating system, I had installed mdadm and had a spanned array of 5 drives appearing as /dev/md0 (none of these had the MBR on them, it was just a new bunch of drives used only for the array). I then mounted /mnt/raiddrvies onto /dev/md0 to access the content. Now the problem is this. Since I've put Ubuntu server onto that SSD, how do I now restore the raid array? I've installed mdadm and tried to run the following command:

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=5 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

When it goes to create the drive, it says the following message for each of the /dev/sd(a,b,d,e, or f):

```
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sda but will be lost or meaningless after creating array
```

At the end it asks:

```
Continue creating an array?
```

I've put no because I want to keep the original array. I just want to re-group them as a single drive and mount it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to **Assemble** your array, not create it. See the man page (mdadm).

Once you do that, back up all your data and start over with a RAID 6 + spare. A linear set basically concatenates all the drive to maximize storage. It also means that if you lose even one of those drives, all of your data is gone.

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#Linear_mode

"Ok, so you have two or more **partitions** (emphasis mine) which are not necessarily the same size (but of course can be), which you want to append to each other.
Spare-disks are not supported here. If a disk dies, the array dies with it. ..."

Comment: Ok I will look how to assemble it. All drives are the same and I want it spanned because I have the data backed up.

Comment: If you're going to span disks like that then, at least use RAID 0, so you can write data in stripes across the whole set instead of writing to blocks 0-100 only to the first drive, 101-200 to the second, and so on. **Much faster**

Comment: Brill, it worked. For anyone else looking to "assemble" the raid array, I used this link for help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=923253

Comment: @johnsmith Great!

Comment: ppetraki, can I please ask you, I didn't know how to describe what is /dev/md0? I know it's my array of drives, but like, what do you call it if you want to create a /dev/md0 (i.e. it's not a mount point, so what do you actually call it)?

Comment: @johnsmith When I work with a HW RAID, I call the entire shelf of disks an array and each logical lun exposed a "raid set". You'll find lots of slang in this area. A stripe is a stripe, but sometimes people call the pieces that make up a stripe a "chunk", others call it an "extent" (a concept that originally came from filesystems), or even a "segment".